# ffmpeg crashing on my ec2 linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

I have a node script that has the line:

`execSync('ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i ${path} -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 ./tmp/%d.ts');`

Basically, I'm splitting a given video into 10 second segments.  This works on my development machine where I have ffmpeg installed:

However, when I push the code to my ec2 instance (running the linux AMI), I get this crash:

`Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i ../test11.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 ./tmp/%d.ts`

I have checked that all the files and directories exist and are organized correctly in both cases.  The only thing I've deduced is that the ffmpeg versions vary between machines, so:

> (developement-Machine)$ ffmpeg -version
>
> (developement-Machine)$ ffmpeg version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>
> (ec2)$ ffmpeg -version
>
> (ec2)$ ffmpeg version N-61041-g52a2138

Is it the case that the ffmpeg version issues are the culprit here and if so how can I get them in sync?  Locally I simply used Homebrew to install ffmpeg.  On the ec2, I've used YUM as a package manager to install node and npm before but it isn't trivial to install ffmpeg.  I've tried to wget the static builds on ffmpeg sites but after un-taring them I get a directory of directories and I'm not sure how to proceed.  The original ffmpeg I installed on my ec2 was here (http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/ffmpeg.static.64bit.2014-02-16.tar.gz)

Either way I am making no progress and I could spend the next 6 hours figuring out what is going on in my linux shell.  So I realize this question is a bit unfocused but is the crash likely an ffmpeg version? and if so, how can I install the local version I have of ffmpeg on my production ec2 server?

Comment: To eliminate surprises : always use the same same Linux distribution when create an instance.  You don't want to deal with third party library issue in various build.  Since you use MacOS , you will not find a OS-X AMI. You need to recompile the same ffmpeg required inside your AMI (and install those missing libraries required by ffmpeg). Or install Virtual machine in your MacOS to load similar linux distro to test your module .

Comment: Can I just get the same version of ffmpeg on my linux that I have on my mac?  Unfortunately its been hours and I'm making little progress on installation on linux as I find it just too confusing.

Comment: First google and check whether there is ready binary package for your linux distro. E.g. Ubuntu,Debian,fedora, redhat, you need to get the exact distribution. If you can't find one, you need to follow this compilation guide for your Linux distro https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

Comment: NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09

Comment: Check this out. 
https://gist.github.com/gboudreau/f24aed76b4cc91bfb2c1
Try the binary suggested by kopurando first.  Try the last OP solution in the github.

Comment: So I wgot and untar/zip'd the binary recommend by kopurando.  what is the best way to set it as a global command?  creating a symlink?  and if so, what symlink specifically.  but really, when i run ./ffmpeg -version in /usr/local/bin I get ( version N-63893-gc69defd) which looks a lot like the original version that caused the problem (at least insofar as its N-##*#)  what I have on my MacOs is Version 3.0.2

Comment: If you go to the fork, you will notice the ffmpeg is copy to /usr/bin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130973/discussion-between-alex-bollbach-and-mootmoot).